# Late 2008 MacBook Pro loose Battery cover fix

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I acquired a Late 2008 MacBook Pro. The bottom cover is a split bottom design. The battery cover is loose around the edge of the laptop. I'm guessing there was a magnetic strip holding it along the edge. It looks like there was a metal strip previously lining the edge but it is missing. The latch is only toward the inside (middle) of the laptop. Could someone confirm/explain how the edge of the cover is held in? I'm hoping I can get some magnetic tape to line the edge of the battery cover.

I'm trying to avoid spending $15-$30 on a replacement cover.

[This](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Unibody+Model+A1278+Access+Door+Replacement/771) is what the battery cover looks like.

Comment: It seems my question was edited to be "MacBook Pro". This is actually a MacBook. It is the only aluminum MacBook ever made. The MacBook differs from the MacBook Pro. Both use different trackpads and the latter has a backlit keyboard while the MacBook does not. However, I don't think the battery cover differs so I'll keep the edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The battery cover is held in place by four metal hooks on the outer edge as shown in the image:

[image]

**Source**: [Macworld/Jason Snell, First Look: MacBook and MacBook Pro](https://www.macworld.com/article/1136063/macbook_first_look.html)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like those are missing on mine.